# capture bitmap and add watermark

Tags: java, android

I trying capture image and set water mark from `onActivityResult` method is fragment from my code.

```
 Private void savingCapturedImage() {
   long date = System.currentTimeMillis();
   Date data = new Date(date);
   File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/Camera", "mobiliskaita.JPG");
   Uri imagePath = Uri.fromFile(file);

    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imagePath);
        System.out.println("bitmap: " + bitmap.getWidth() + " " + bitmap.getHeight());
        file.delete();
        bitmap = mark(bitmap, String.valueOf(data), 100, 200, 100, false);
        bitmap = mark(bitmap, TheGlobals.partneriaiValue, 100, 310, 100, false);


        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        bitmap.recycle();
        File fileOutput = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/Camera", photoName());
        fileOutput.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(fileOutput);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.flush();
        fo.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


  private Bitmap mark(Bitmap src, String watermark, int x, int y, int size, boolean underline) {
    int w = src.getWidth();
    int h = src.getHeight();
    Point _p = new Point();
    _p.x = x;
    _p.y = y;

    final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int p = (int) (900 * scale + 0.5f);

    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(src, p, p, true);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
    canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, null);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setTextSize(R.dimen.default_text_size);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setUnderlineText(underline);
    canvas.drawText(watermark, _p.x, _p.y, paint);

    return result;
}
```

It's working but then i have camer with 8 or more megapixels, i get `out of memory` expection. Maybe someone can help my solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bitmap from the camera is going to be big, if you're only going to save it as 900x900, then you may have to use another method of reading it (not MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap()), one where you can set the inSampleSize: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile(java.lang.String, android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options)

You could also recycle src in mark() after you've drawn it to the canvas. At the moment you are creating 2 900x900dp bitmaps, so merging the 2 calls to mark might also help.

Comment: I'm try to do like u said, it almost good, but i have another problem
[link]http://www.part.lt/img/eb4e149bc162f8ce4ccb9249fd1ca22c384.jpg, whatch picture, get one normal picture and another 1/2 smaller on it. :)

Comment: okay, solved that problem, another LAST ONE!! then i captured image and save, it change orientation.